# AngularJS : using Two.js, Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to create an edit polygon using AngularJS : i used this function  but i have error :Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null.

Controller AngularJS  :

```
  var two = new Two({ type: Two.Types.svg }).appendTo(document.getElementById("ImgCamera"));
    var polygon = new Two.Polygon(10,10,5,4)
    $scope.drawWheel = function () {
        var center_X = 420;
        var center_Y = 140;
        var radius = 100;
        var ellipse = $scope.two.makeEllipse(center_X, center_Y, radius, radius);
        ellipse.linewidth = 0;
        ellipse.fill = "#66BB6A";
        var spoke_color = "#FF5722";
        var x1 = center_X;
        var y1 = center_Y;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.spokes; i++) {
            var x2 = x1 + radius * Math.cos(i * 5);
            var y2 = y1 + radius * Math.sin(i * 5);
            var line = self.two.makeLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            line.linewidth = 3;
            line.stroke = "white";
        }
        self.two.update();
    }
```

HTML code :

```
<div id="ImgCamera">
    <div ng-init="drawWheel()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which line throws an error? first: `var two = new Two({...`?

Comment: yes this line throws an error i can't succeded to resolve them. have you an idea please

Comment: Need more code.
Create a sample your code on jsfiddle.